# No Cortana after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana, windows-10-upgrade

I used to enjoy Cortana on my Nokia Lumia  435 when i had Windows 8.1. For instance pressing continuously the search button opened Cortana and I could command it to :

- Call a person on my contacts
- Sms a person on my contacts
- Launch any app installed

When a text came in as I was listening to music on my earphone or even bluetooth headset I would here Cortana asking me to allow it to read me the new text.
Now after upgrade I can't enjoy of these great features. I am wondering why I upgraded.
What should I do to enjoy Cortana on my Windows 10? Is there a way to downgrade? Windows 8.1 was much better that 10.

Comment: "*I am wondering why i upgraded.*" I am wondering what your question is :)

Comment: I have updated my question so dont wonder

Comment: Check your phone's region, language and speech settings. Verify that they are all set to languages that Cortana supports (and ideally to the same language).

Answer (score 1):

Try language and region settings .

Cortana works only when you match your language and region. For example: Cortana won't work if I set my language in Chinese, but set my region in the U.S. It only works when I set both language and region to Chinese.

If this does not work, the most simple solution is to restore your Windows Phone, and re-set all your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering what are you saying. I experienced just reverse of your question. No Cortana before upgradation because my phone and region do not match.It is because in WP8.1, Cortana works only when you match your language and region which is not mandatory for W10M. Just a few features won't work if you do not match all the settings and nothing else. Now I am using Cortana and it is doing very well. Now I am listening to texts, doing stuff by voice commands and much more. The steps you're needed to follow are:

- Please make sure you are fully updated (I am running on 14393.448) .
- then long press search icon of the navigation bar.
- Now tap the triple bars at the top-right of the screen.
- Look for "Why Cortana is not available on my device?".
- Then tap on "Learn More".

Also have a look on [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=522359). Hopefully this helps.